# Is it true $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Is it true $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{2})$?
If yes prove it if not explain why

I can show that  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{2})$ ⊂  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2})$
but im not sure that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2})$ ⊂ $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Comment: You should use mathjax when writing any mathematics in your posts. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for an easy guide.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you mean with `\root(3)(2)`?

Comment: cube root 2..  sorry im trying to learn how to write in mathjax

Comment: @YouseonJung Fixed your question, check whether it is correct or not. On the contrary, here's a quick guide to MathJax on this site : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: it's still not perfect.. but i think now you can recognize the question

Comment: @YouseonJung, That's not my edit. It's someone else's. My edit is still waiting for approval

Comment: Note that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ satisfies $X^3 - 2 = 0$. From this, we see that $(X - \sqrt[3]{2})^3 - 2 = 0$ for $X = \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt{2}$. Expand the cube and use this equation to write $\sqrt{2}$ as a  rational function of $X$. If you have been able to complete this approach even partially, please record your attempts in the question post. (MathJax usage would be ideal but not necessary). For an example where this was successfully executed, see Lubin's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642126/find-basis-of-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt34).

Comment: @YouseonJung Check out [this older thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1715265/11619). I think some of the answers there address your question, also.

Comment: You may also want to use [ApproachZero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cmathbb%7BQ%7D(%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%2C%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B2%7D)%24&p=1). Do take your time familiarizing yourself with the site before delving into that tool. I only bring it up, because that's how I found the closely related thread. And ApproachZero is one of the few search engines that grok MathJax. For example Google cannot manage.

Answer (score 1):

They both have degree 6 over $\mathbb{Q}$ and one field is contained in the other. By the tower law they are the same.

Comment: "They both have degree 6" really needs a justification. Especially that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]2)$  has degree 6.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken ( I haven't tried) but it seems like a standard calculation of the minimal polynomial to me.

Comment: I don't know what the minimal polynomial is, but it's always a risky approach because it may be difficult to show that it's irreducible.

Comment: Hmm I get your point... I calculated the minimal polynomial as $ x^6 - 6 x^4 - 4 x^3 + 12 x^2 - 24 x - 4$ and it's not obvious this is irreducible.